# Meaning of LED signals in SATDOCK22RE disk duplicator by StarTech

Tags: hard-drive

We've just received a disk duplicator from StarTech - the `SATDOCK22RE`.

It looks like a nice system, but the manual is not clear about the various signals that the LEDs show.

Specifically, after we pressed the start button to duplicate disks we see:

- For `HDD1` and 2 both `red` and `blue` are on, giving a sort of violet, and the first bar of the progress bar is flashing.  This has been unchanging for 2 hours.
- The PC/Copy button is red (copy).

What does this mean, and are there any other LED indications that are not documented that we should know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree, I am glad I am not the only one that sees the violet light on the HDD indicator. Now I've been told the same, red (or what I call violet) means the drive is not read properly, well guess what, the red (or what I call violet) is the ONLY mode that worked... I have tried duplicating about 10 drives... all but 2 failed, both the worked were violet in color. I contacted support and I was told that because of some drives having a restricted partition, the duplicator could not write over it. I was asked to do a Low Level format on the drive. I did, spent 5 hours doing a low level format on two different drives to no avail, still one drive is blue and the other is violet. When they mismatch, THEY WILL NOT DUPLICATE.

Now, I continued troubleshooting and discovered that the 8 that did not work (all with the blue light) since they all matched each other with the blue light, they all copied among themselves, but you CANNOT duplicate from violet to blue or blue to violet, they both have to be the same color. Which tech support could not give me an explanation. A couple of the drives that had the mismatch (red and blue) were identical models with identical size... go figure...

Answer (score 3):

From [Startech.com](http://www.startech.com/media/products/SATDOCK22RE/PDFs/SATDOCK22RE.pdf)

LED Indicators: 2 - Drive Status (Blue - drive detected, Red - drive not detected, Flashing Red - Activity)
• LED Indicators: 1 - Power Indicator (Blue)
• LED Indicators: 1 - Mode Indicator (Blue - JBOD, Red - Duplication)
• LED Indicators: 1 - Progress Bar (Blue)

[Latest Manual](http://www.startech.com/media/products/SATDOCK22RE/Manuals/SATDOCK22RE.pdf) is here.

I also suggest calling their support or using their online chat.  It is usually quick and they are pretty good.

By the way, a duplication with this dock can take some time.  How big are the disks you are duplicating?